# Digi XCTU 7.0 not recognizing Xbee Pro SX but can recover without issue

Tags: xbee

I've assembled a custom PCB that has a Xbee Pro SX on it. After not using it for about a month, I am unable to add it to XCTU, or to communicate with it over UART. However, I am able to use Xbee Recovery to reset the firmware without issue, so I know it's hooked up correctly to my UART/USB converter. What do I need to do to communicate with this module?

As a side note, why are Digi's support forums so shitty? I posted this question three days ago on their forums and it still hasn't been "checked and approved". I'm not even asking for somebody from Digi to reply, just want to post the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a hold of a Xbee engineer, turns out the USB/UART cable was providing *just* under the required current. The module was turning on/off, which is why I was having trouble communicating with it. When I had tested it before, I was using a desktop power supply in a lab (which could provide plenty of current).